# Custom AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocation> does not trigger the `check` method

Tags: spring, spring-security

According to
[this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#jc-method-security-custom-authorization-manager) documentation of spring security I added a custom `AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocation>`

While the bean got triggered

```
@Bean
@Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
public Advisor customAuthorize() {
    JdkRegexpMethodPointcut pattern = new JdkRegexpMethodPointcut();
    pattern.setPattern("xxx.*");

    AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocation> rule = new CustomAuthorizationManager();
    AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor interceptor = new AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor(pattern, rule);
    interceptor.setOrder(AuthorizationInterceptorsOrder.PRE_AUTHORIZE.getOrder() - 1);
    return interceptor;
}
```

Below `check` method does not trigger the `UnsupportedOperationException` at all.

```
public class CustomAuthorizationManager implements AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocation> {
    @Override
    public AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier<Authentication> authentication, MethodInvocation object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unimplemented method 'check'");
    }
}
```

Any advice what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of the `JdkRegexpMethodPointcut` expression. This did not match the Controllers namespace. In my case I had to set it the following

```
pattern.setPattern("de.domain.subdomain.Controller.*");
```